# I Ran out of space to extract a .rar file, i downloaded the file using C: Drive can i extract the file using a external hard drive?

Tags: windows-10, winrar

I ran out of space to extract a 50Gb .rar file. I downloaded the file using C: hard drive, could I use an external hard drive to extract the .rar file? I don't have an external hard drive but thinking about getting one to extract the file, so would it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With most "unzip" tools (all that I am familiar with) you can point the extract to any drive.

So, yes, you can point the extract to an external drive. That will work.

Comment: Thanks for the help, John. I ended up getting a hard drive and it works as intended. Thanks again!